# How to randomly assign integers that equal the input of a specific cell (Excel)

Tags: excel

I have been working on this basic excel model which predicts Facebook analytics based on the budget we would like to set.

If you plug in 500$ you can get to see the total amount of page likes. 
Each time you plug in a new budget this figure will change.

Estimating daily likes is very difficult & sort of pointless so I thought I could fill up the empty cells with randomly assigned numbers which have a sum equal to the total amount of 940 likes in that specific cell.

The trick is, I would like it so that when I change the input budget, these randomly assigned numbers change as well but always sum up to the total.

For clarity I have attached a snapshot below:

I would like to randomly divide cell G51(940 likes) across cells: G20-G50 to mimic daily likes. The sum of cells G20-G50 needs to equal cell G51 and change respectively when the integer in G51 changes.

[Excel Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G1Ye9.png)

Look forward to your replies! Thanks again for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since we are filling **G20** through **G50** *(31 cells)*, the average value of each cell will be about *30.3*.  In **G20** enter:

```
=ROUND(G$51/31,0)+RANDBETWEEN(-10,10)
```

and copy down through **G49**

To match the sum to **G51**, in **G50** enter:

```
=G51-SUM(G20:G49)
```

[image]

If the value in **G50** shows negative, just re-calculate the worksheet.

*There ae other methods that improve the "randomness", but they involve extra columns.*

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick response! This formula is exactly what I needed-it works great.